# Conteúdo de um input no HREF

Tags: php

Como eu faço para que a pessoa seja redirecionada pra uma URL + oque ela digitar?

Exemplo

A pessoa digita **batata** no input abaixo

```html
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
```

E quando aperta enter é redirecionada pra

www.google.com/search?q=**batata**

Comment: pode ser javascript ou tem de ser php?

Comment: De jeito fácil é só usar um form com method=get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se de fato precisa usar PHP  pra fazer isso que você quer! Se for só um campo! Pode usar usar um form com `method="get"`

Mas caso não queira fazer dessa maneira, basta capturar o valor do input, adicionar o valor a uma variável e inserir numa URL, e fazer um redirecionamento com o header do PHP

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.site_a_ser_redirecionado.com/search=".$variavel.""); ?>
```

Comment: Ivan, voce pode usar ` ` no lugar de `<code>` e `</code>` (ou marcar o trecho de código e apertar control k).

Comment: @Bacco qual a diferença ?

Comment: @MagicHat na saída praticamente não tem, mas fica mais legivel para quem for mexer no fonte da postagem, e é o jeito oficial de formatar. Na verdade, eu não entendo a razão da rede permitir HTML se já tem o Markdown. Aqui tem um resumo bom: [Ajuda do Markdown](/editing-help)

Comment: Concordo, com a melhor manutenção, e foi isso que pensei... Alguns já podiam ter moderado isso. Agora fica a dúvida, do por quê, isso é permitido ou qual a possível vantagem de não bloquear.